# How to improve Postgres performance using Prepare?

Tags: postgresql

In this query, an inner join is repeated every time,
imagine billions of orders and hundreds of stores...

```
PREPARE findNextId(uuid) AS(
    WITH producedNextIds AS(
         WITH ordersOfStore AS (
        SELECT
             "order"."id", "order"."createdAt"
         From
             "order"
         INNER JOIN "site" ON "order"."storeId" = "site"."id"
        )
        SELECT "id" , "createdAt",
            LEAD("id",1) OVER (
                ORDER BY "createdAt"
                ) next_id
        FROM
            ordersOfStore
    )
        SELECT
            "id" , "createdAt", next_id
        FROM producedNextIds
        WHERE
            "id" = ($1)
);
EXECUTE findNextId('cb5c5bf0-f781-46e1-9ae1-68c875bb3a56');
```

does `PREPARE` make Postgres cache the join until the session ends up?
is there a more performant way of doing the query?

Comment: No, Prepare does not cache any intermediate results

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Why the CTEs? This can be written as a simple join: http://dpaste.com/3PZT9H2 which might actually lead to a better plan (especially with Postgres 11 or earlier)

Comment: To use multiple CTEs you should chain them, not nest them: `with cte_one as (...), cte_two as (select ... from cte_one) select * from cte_two`

Comment: thanks for the notes. so no way to cache queries in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Postgres will cache the underlying data blocks, but not the result of a query